# Authentication with the choice of multiple OpenID providers

Tags: c#, .net, openid, dotnetopenauth

I want to setup a basic authentication page where a user has a choice of OpenID providers to login with it will redirect them to the OpenID provider to login and once a successful login is complete the user is directly to a congratulations page. Could someone give me some help or advice on code examples that can be used to help me? I had a look at dotnetopenauth but it is very confusing, I was hopefully looking for something a bit more basic.

Thanks,

Steven

Answer (score 0):

Janrain have a product that looks easy to use: http://developers.janrain.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the confusion in DotNetOpenAuth may be in the samples alone.  Actually wiring it up in an app is most often quite simple.  If you're using ASP.NET web forms, adding a Yahoo button (for example), is as simple as adding this tag:

```
<rp:OpenIdButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/yahoo.png" Text="Login with Yahoo!" ID="yahooLoginButton" Identifier="https://me.yahoo.com/" />
```

The button is fully functional immediately.

If you're using ASP.NET MVC, you can check out the OpenIdRelyingPartyMvc sample that comes with the library.  MVC necessarily removes the simplicity of a single tag, but it's still pretty simple.